# How to click on specific cluster externally using Google Maps MarkerClusterer Library?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have made a sample page to generate Clusters of Markers using Google Maps MarkerClusterer Library as linked below
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

The sample page code is same as this one
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/examples/simple_example.html

What I want to do is, I want to put a Button on this page and when I click on it, I want to call a Javascript function which will pass some kind of identification for the Clusters and based on that Identification, that cluster's click event will be called. I tried to look into the API reference of this library but did not find how to identify the Clusters. So finally decided to put it here.

Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Interesting, I see your use case for this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the clusters will always change based on zoom level, so to say a cluster can be ID'ed would be invalid - right?

Comment: There is the getClusters() function which returns an array of clusters.  And you can trigger a click event on an individual cluster. So if you were able to associate your button with an individual cluster in the array, it should be possible.